# Overlap sibling view with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout at the top of my app. Below the RelativeLayout I have a ViewPager.

To explain this in a way that will make sense, imagine the screen's height is 700 pixels. The RelativeLayout is about 200 pixels high.

I want the RelativeLayout to be position absolutely at the top of the app such that the ViewPager is behind it. I then want to add a 200 pixel `paddingTop` to the ViewPager so that it appears under the RelativeLayout.

Here is the layout I have now (which is obviously not working):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I load a ListView with some data under the `header`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the linearlayout to a framelayout. This will allow the views to be placed on top of each other.

Then put the code for the pageviewer above the relativelayout. This will make the pageviewer appear to be behind the relativelayout as it is rendered first, and the relativelayout rendered on top of it. Android will render views in the order in which they are declared.

Lastly, add a top margin/padding to the pageviewer to make it seem positioned below the relativelayout.

Comment: Same problem with the other solution. This keeps the `header` in a fixed position, meaning that if I scroll down, it stays in its position.

Comment: I should mention that below the `header` is a ListView that I'm loading. I added the code to the question.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're trying to achieve. Please make a simple mockup (done in paint or whatever) to illustrate how you want it to look like, and then add it to the question.

Comment: Do you use the Twitter app? If you go to someone's profile page, you'll notice at the top they have a layout for the profile information (like the description, # of followers, etc). Below that they have a ListView that has posts from that user. You can also swipe left or right to go to the next ListView (Tweets, Photos, and Favorites). When you scroll vertically, the header scrolls down with the ListView. If you scroll left or right, the header doesn't change but the ListView content does. That's what I want to replicate. Image of the Twitter app: http://i.imgur.com/dUbxrFJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

- Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as the root.
- Move the ViewPager(pager) view to the top of child RelativeLayout(header)

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/pager"
          android:paddingTop="200px"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />            
      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Comment: This keeps the `header` in a fixed position, meaning that if I scroll down, it stays in its position. I need it to scroll normally (with the ViewPager).

Comment: I should mention that below the `header` is a ListView that I'm loading. I added the code to the question.

Comment: @user5291000 if you want to replicate the twitter profile layout, the ListView should be put inside of the ViewPager.